# How to change view REST export format

Tags: views, 8

This is my settings in view.

[image]

Data what I have is now in this format:

```
[{"created":"1551709414","field_iot_integer":"43"},
{"created":"1551709404","field_iot_integer":"98"},
{"created":"1551709392","field_iot_integer":"58"},
{"created":"1551709382","field_iot_integer":"4"},
{"created":"1551709373","field_iot_integer":"65"},
{"created":"1551709356","field_iot_integer":"23"}]
```

I would like to change this format in this, rid of all comments. :

```
[[1551709414,43],
[1551709404,98],
[1551709392,58],
[1551709382,4],
[1551709373,65],
[1551709356,23]]
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change the structure of the `Serializer` output you should create a custom `Serializer` here is the steps of your use case:

1. Create `CustomSerializer` extends the `Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\style\Serializer` and update the `render` method to your needs.

   - Create `MY_MODULE/Plugin/views/style/CustomSerializer.php`

```
namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\views\style;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\style\Serializer;

/**
 * The style plugin for serialized output formats.
 *
 * @ingroup views_style_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsStyle(
 *   id = "custom_serializer",
 *   title = @Translation("Custom serializer"),
 *   help = @Translation("Serializes views row data using the Serializer
 *   component."), display_types = {"data"}
 * )
 */
class CustomSerializer extends Serializer {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render() {
    $rows = [];
    // If the Data Entity row plugin is used, this will be an array of entities
    // which will pass through Serializer to one of the registered Normalizers,
    // which will transform it to arrays/scalars. If the Data field row plugin
    // is used, $rows will not contain objects and will pass directly to the
    // Encoder.
    foreach ($this->view->result as $row_index => $row) {
      $this->view->row_index = $row_index;
      $row_render = $this->view->rowPlugin->render($row);
      $iot_integer = 0;
      if (isset($row_render["field_iot_integer"]) && $row_render["field_iot_integer"] instanceof \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup){
        $iot_integer = (int) $row_render["field_iot_integer"]->__toString();
      }
     $rows[] = [
        $row_render["created"]->__toString(),
       $iot_integer
      ];
    }
    unset($this->view->row_index);

    // Get the content type configured in the display or fallback to the
    // default.
    if ((empty($this->view->live_preview))) {
      $content_type = $this->displayHandler->getContentType();
    }
    else {
      $content_type = !empty($this->options['formats']) ? reset($this->options['formats']) : 'json';
    }
    return $this->serializer->serialize($rows, $content_type, ['views_style_plugin' => $this]);
  }
}
```

2. Clear Cache:
3. Go to your view and change the format from `Serializer` to `Custom serializer` like
   [image]
4. The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is very good. I understood that I was need to extend class Serializer but didn't know to write function.

Comment: you are welcome, glad that help.

Comment: Hi i have the same problem, but when i've created those files i dont have that option "Custom serializer" in views, could you please help me?

Comment: Did you put the files in the right structure, and you check that your module is enabled and did you cleared the cache ?